# Query to output a desired results

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables that are populated with four main columns of data.

The first table main columns are date (DD-MON-YY), field, category and volume1 for that category.

```
Date        field       category    volume1
31-jan-14   Farm        111         100000
28-feb-14   Farm        222         130000
28-feb-13   Farm        212         150000
```

The second table main columns are date (DD-MON-YY), field, category and volume2 for that category.

```
Date        field       category    volume2
31-jan-14   Farm        444         100000
28-feb-14   Farm        525         130000
28-feb-13   Farm        625         150000
```

The field names can exist in both tables but the category column is not.

I want to tabulate an output from these two tables that consist of the date, field, and volume1 and volume2 data.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this query.

```
SELECT f.Date, f.field, f.volume1
FROM  firstTable f
UNION
SELECT s.Date, s.field, s.volume2
FROM  secondTable s
```

Comment: Thanks Rizvi, how can you show the results into two columns volume1 and volume2 instead of two rows.

Comment: Can you add your output in your question?

Comment: http://dwhlaureate.blogspot.jp/2012/08/joins-in-oracle.html...you can study this tutorial, it may clear you. If you are not clear, then add your output with your question. You will get answer soon.